# Undefined reference to initialized static member variable with make_shared

Tags: c++, static, undefined-reference, make-shared

Compiling with -std=c++14 the following code:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    static constexpr int c = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<int> b;

    A()     {
        b = std::make_shared<int> (c);
    }

};

int main () {
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives a linker error "undefined reference to `A::c'", while using "A::c" in other contexts that are not "make_shared", this error doesn't occur. In particular, the following code compiles and works correctly:

```
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr int c = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<int> b;

    A()     {
        int cc = c;
        b = std::make_shared<int> (cc);
    }

};
```

Comment: Please also show your compiler version and compile command

Comment: I compiled it with c++14, with c++17 it works, what is the problem with c++14?

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: note - reopened; someone closed as duplicate of a question that didn't cover why `make_shared` caused the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 the first code should work correctly: a `static constexpr` class member variable is implicitly [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) which means the compiler takes care of making sure a definition exists .

Prior to C++17 the code has undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required) due to ODR violation.  A static class member that is [*odr-used*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) must also have an out-of-line definition.

Binding a reference to a variable counts as *odr-use*, and that happens with [`make_shared<int>(c)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) since that function is defined as :

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

so the argument is bound to a reference parameter.

---

In theory you should be able to work around it with `make_shared<int>(+c)` ... then the reference is bound to the temporary result of `+c` and not to `c` itself, therefore there is no odr-use. Similar theory to your posted workaround in the question.

`enum { c = 0 };` is another possible workaround, if the type is `int` in the real code .